# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: while using multiple router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new in angular. I am creating a portal web application with angular 6.

This project has a login form and some user environment pages. In user environment pages header, footer and aside menu are common between all pages but these are not visible in login page. So, I decided to assign two `<router-outlet>` tag with different names for that.

my codes in app.component.html are like below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet name="without_header_and_footer"></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="admin_panel"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

After that I create two services for authentication named `AuthGuardService` and `GuestGuardService` which control access to login form and user environment pages.

These two services codes are like below:

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate , CanActivateChild{
  constructor(private authService: AuthService , private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<boolean>
    | Promise<boolean>
    | boolean {
return this.authService.isLogin().then((isLogin) => {
  if(isLogin){
    return true;
  }
  this.router.navigate([
    {
      outlets: {
        without_header_and_footer: ['']
      }
    }
  ]);
});
  }

  canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<boolean>
    | Promise<boolean>
    | boolean {
    return this.canActivate(childRoute , state);
  }
}
```

**guest-guard.service.ts**

```
export class GuestGuardService implements CanActivate , CanActivateChild{
  constructor(private authService: AuthService , private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: 
RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<boolean>
    | Promise<boolean>
    | boolean {
return this.authService.isLogin().then((isLogin) => {
  if(!isLogin){
    return true;
  }
  this.router.navigate([
    {
      outlets: {
        admin_panel: ['home']
      }
    }
  ]);
});
  }

  canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
Observable<boolean>
| Promise<boolean>
| boolean {
return this.canActivate(childRoute , state);
  }
}
```

`authService` variables which injected in contructors of these two classes are instanced from AuthService class which is like below:

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
  loggedIn: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  isLogin(){
const promise = new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    return resolve(this.loggedIn);
  } , 1000);
});
return promise;
  }

  login(){
    this.loggedIn = true;
  }

  logout(): void{
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import {AppRouting} from './app-routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import {AuthGuardService} from "./services/auth/auth-guard.service";
import {GuestGuardService} from "./services/auth/guest-guard.service";
import {AuthService} from "./services/auth/auth.service";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRouting
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuardService,
    GuestGuardService,
    AuthService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './components/login/login.component';
import {HomeComponent} from "./components/home/home.component";
import {AuthGuardService} from "./services/auth/auth-guard.service";
import {GuestGuardService} from "./services/auth/guest-guard.service";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: LoginComponent ,
    outlet: 'without_header_and_footer',
    canActivate: [GuestGuardService],
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    outlet: 'admin_panel',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRouting {}
```

And finally my routes are like below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: LoginComponent ,
    outlet: 'without_header_and_footer',
    canActivate: [GuestGuardService],
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    outlet: 'admin_panel',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  }
];
```

It seems every things is correct. But when I want to navigate to route `/home` below error were shown in console:

`core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'`

Comment: Can you please post your app module code and how are you navigating to home?

Comment: I was added app.module.ts file content.

Comment: You have not registered your routes in Router module.

Comment: I was entered localhost:4200/home in address bar of browser

Comment: I registred them in AppRouting file and imported it in imports section of app.module.ts

Comment: What is the content of AppRouting file?

Comment: Now, I write it's content in my post.

Comment: Ritesh, I wrote app-routing.ts file content in my post.

Comment: Farhad, is your issue fixed?

Comment: No, That's not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Change you aap.routing.ts file to:

```
import {LoginComponent} from './components/login/login.component';
import {HomeComponent} from "./components/home/home.component";
import {AuthGuardService} from "./services/auth/auth-guard.service";
import {GuestGuardService} from "./services/auth/guest-guard.service";

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: LoginComponent ,
    outlet: 'without_header_and_footer',
    canActivate: [GuestGuardService],
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    outlet: 'admin_panel',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  }
];
```

and then in your app.module.ts file import appRoutes like this:

```
import { appRoutes } from './app.routing.ts'
```

and replace your import array to:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ]
```